# Write values to before created object with PropertyAccesor

Tags: php, symfony, accessor

I have a class the gets fed strings with the name of my database fields and the according values. I want to create a new entry and want to check beforehand if the field exists in my database.
However, since the object is created just before I check if the Property is readable, it throws an exception:

> Fails Here: Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty

The error is thrown here:

```
try{
    $accessor->isWritable($field['name'], $hw);
}catch (\Exception $exception){
    throw new \Exception('Fails Here: '.$exception->getMessage());
}
```

#### Disclaimer

I know this is dangerous and can cause harm due to injection, but this is an internal project with only me as a user, and I currently can't think of a more elegant way to do this, without writing an `add_new_row` or similar function for every table.

#### Example

- The table `Hardware` has the columns `SerialNo`, `Firmware` and `BuyDate`.
- The table `Product` has the columns `isActive` and `Price`

Via ajax I now want to send an array for each of the tables to create a new entry. I get an array like this via `$.post()`:

```
$data = array(
    'table' => 'Hardware',
    'values' => array(
        0 => array(
            'name' => 'SerialNo',
            'value' => '1234'
        ),
        1 => array(
            'name' => 'Firmware',
            'value' => 'v1.04'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'name' => 'BuyDate',
            'value' => '2018-08-23'
        ),
    )
)
```

So in order to use the same class for every table (`Hardware` and `Product` for example) I tried to do this:

```
$accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();

if($data['table'] === 'Hardware'){
    $obj = new Hardware();
}else{
    $obj = new Product();
}

foreach ($data['values'] as $field) {

    try{
        $accessor->isWritable($field['name'], $hw);
    }catch (\Exception $exception){
        throw new \Exception('Fails Here: '.$exception->getMessage());
    }

    if (!$accessor->isWritable($field['name'], $obj)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Could not write: ' . $field['name']);
    }

    $accessor->setValue($field['name'], $obj, $field['value']);
    $em->persist($obj);
}
```

It does not even throw the exception, and I think it is because `$obj` looks like this (this is what the error thrown means, isn't it?)

`Hardware {#2708 ▼
  -id: null
  -serialNo: null
  -firmware: null
  -buyDate: null`

Is there any way to do this they way I wanted it?

Comment: Where is this error thrown? Do you get a stack trace? What is the actual value that is passed to `isset()` or `empty()` that leads to this failure?

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the parameters for `isWritable()` and `setValue()`. If you swap them like this, your code will work as expected:

```
if (!$accessor->isWritable($obj, $field['name'])) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException('Could not write: ' . $field['name']);
}

$accessor->setValue($obj, $field['name'], $field['value']);
```